# Code is not working (C++ unions and structures)

Tags: c++, structure, unions

No matter how many times I reformat this, I keep getting all kinds of errors. The end result will be a program that can save functions targeting motors in a telescope and set coordinates. Any help in explaining what I am doing wrong with this setup would be greatly appreciated. here is the code:

`//IDENTIFY RECEIVER OF MESSAGE / TYPE OF MESSAGE / VIEW ALL TO 1 DEVICE / VIEW SPECIFIC MESSAGE`

```
 #include "messaging.h"
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct MGR{
mess_types messagetype;
int DeviceID;
union E{
    //why arte these underlined? 
    char INST[STRSIZE];
    int codes[NBRCODES];
    float coords[NBRCOORDS];
} message;
};// info;


void messager(){
MGR my_data;
my_data.messagetype = INST;
my_data.DeviceID = TECH1;
strcpy(my_data.message.INST, "GO HOME");

my_data.messagetype = CODES;
my_data.DeviceID = MOTOR1;
for (int nbr = 0; nbr < NBRCODES; nbr++){
    my_data.message.codes[nbr] = nbr;
    print_message(my_data);
}
}
int print_message(MGR mydata){
MGR noot;
scanf("%s", &mydata);
switch (mydata.messagetype){
case INST:
    printf("Message to Device %d", noot.DeviceID);
    break;
case CODES:
    printf("The setup codes for device %d are: \n", noot.DeviceID);
    for (int code = 0; code < NBRCODES + OFFSET; code++){
        printf("%4d\t", noot.message);
    }
        break;
case COORDS:
    printf("The setup codes for device %d are: \n", noot.DeviceID);
    for (int code = 0; code < NBRCODES + OFFSET; code++){
        printf("%4d\t", noot.message);
    }
        break;
    }
    printf("%c", mydata.messagetype);
    return(0)
    }

    void Sendmessage(){
        printf("This program does not work... it is under construction...");
}
```

Just in case: here is the header file

```
#include "sprint1.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define STRSIZE 50
#define NBRCODES 200
#define NBRCOORDS 200
#define OFFSET 100
#define FACTOR 50
#define TECH1 123
#define MOTOR1 4556
void messager();
int print_message(MGR mydata);
void Sendmessage();
enum mess_types {INST, CODES, COORDS};
```

Error list: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0CXbbHDOrweQVVvOVU1M0VRaEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you are getting errors you should share them.  You do not need to show all of the but at least the first few.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting ? Where in the code? Have you tried debugging a bit ?

Comment: It was showing me no errors in the code until I tried to run it, but nothing was underlined. One that I fixed already are adding a semicolon after the return. It is saying that MGR is an undeclared identifier and I'm missing some parentheses somewhere.

Comment: Please add the actual error text to the question.  paraphrasing a error does no one any good.

Comment: Could anyone who is downvoting me please explain what I am doing wrong? I am still new here.

Comment: You are being downvoted because the question cannot be answered in its existing state. You are asking about a large number of compiler errors and not providing all of the code that generates them. Do bnot write code this way. Write a little bit of code. Compile it, test it, and then write a little bit more. Don't let errors build up because they may play off each other making solving them harder for you. At stack overflow you want one problem, or a tight grouping of problems, per question. This question is about a dozen problems in one.

Comment: The compiler wants to know, among other things, what is a `MGR`? I see `MGR` in the above code, but it is declared AFTER it is required by the header. By the way, it looks like you're learning C, not C++. the `typedef` in `typedef struct MGR` is unnecessary in C++ and is causing one of the later warnings.

Comment: Thanks. putting the structure in the header helped a lot. This is all the code in the section that is having issues, as the full program is quite a bit larger and this is only 1 program in it. I'll update with any other fixes in case anyone happens along a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the header listed is "messaging.h"

MGR is referenced in the header before it's definition in the code.
Maybe move the definition to the header before the first reference.

Comment: Correct, but that just exposes OP to "What is `mess_types`?" so that needs to be moved as well. And don't get me started on how [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) and [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) are being abused. By the time you've sorted it all you you'll have rewritten half of OP's code. Steer away from these sorts of open-ended questions because you can never fully answer them.

Comment: Thanks:) that got rid of the errors. I had to put the enum ahead of the structure, which is now in the header.